# SQL Update query with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask for help with my query. I can't understand how to do it.

I have table where I have items (from game) and I need to change their displayid column according to value from other item

When I run this query I have that items

```
SELECT displayid, name, class, subclass, allowablerace, allowableclass, inventorytype FROM item_template WHERE name LIKE '%S1%';
```

I will get result - note this is eq where name contains S1

```
 displayid name                                 class subclass allowablerace allowableclass inventorytype
 39296 Druid S1 Balance Staff                    2       10            -1             -1            17
 39296 Druid S1 Resto Staff                      2       10            -1             -1            17
 31864 Shaman S1 Ele Dagger                      2       15            -1             -1            13
 42376 Shaman S1 Shield                          4        6            -1             -1            14
 31864 Shaman S1 Resto Dagger                    2       15            -1             -1            13
 38679 Warrior S1 Thrown                         2       16            -1             -1            25
```

-- this return items with name containing deadly

```
SELECT displayid, name, class, subclass, allowablerace, allowableclass, inventorytype FROM item_template WHERE name LIKE '%Deadly%';

 displayid  name                                         class  subclass  allowablerace  allowableclass  inventorytype 
 55817  Deadly Gladiator's Dreadplate Chestpiece         4         4          32767              32              5 
 55816  Deadly Gladiator's Scaled Chestpiece             4         4          32767               2              5 
 55811  Deadly Gladiator's Plate Chestpiece              4         4          32767               1              5 
 55812  Deadly Gladiator's Plate Gauntlets               4         4     2147483647               1             10
```

My question is how to make that Deadly Item DisplayID will be set for S1 items where conditions meat like same class, subclass, allowablerace, allowableclass, inventorytype

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
UPDATE item_template SET displayid = (SELECT displayID FROM item_template c) WHERE inventorytype = c.inventorytype AND class = c.class AND subclass = c.subclass AND allowableclass = c.allowableclass AND name LIKE '%S1%' AND c.name LIKE '%Deadly%';
```

Sorry for bad english

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want here is an update self join:

```
UPDATE item_template it1
INNER JOIN item_template it2
    ON it1.inventorytype = it2.inventorytype AND
       it1.class = it2.class AND
       it1.subclass = it2.subclass AND
       it1.allowableclass = it2.allowableclass
SET
    it1.displayid = it2.displayid
WHERE
    it1.name LIKE '%S1%' AND
    it2.name LIKE '%Deadly%';
```

Comment: Correct order should be first SET then WHERE no ? Also t1 and t2 should it1 it2, but anyway thank's, I was looking for that.